Issue creating table using SQL in Databricks GCP (Google clould)
I am trying to create a table from a csv stored in DBFS using this code:
CREATE TABLE tablesql  
USING csv  
OPTIONS ( 
 path "dbfs:/datasources/data-test.csv", 
 header "true" 
)

This same technique is mentioned on the doc: https://docs.gcp.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-using.html and also on this course https://www.linkedin.com/learning/databricks-certified-data-engineer-associate-cert-prep-3-incremental-data-processing?contextUrn=urn%3Ali%3AlyndaLearningPath%3A65ce725134509d7bccae2c65&u=0
But I keep having this issue that mentions that dbfs is not supported contrary to the refs

[UC_FILE_SCHEME_FOR_TABLE_CREATION_NOT_SUPPORTED]
Creating table in Unity Catalog with file scheme dbfs is not supported. -- Instead, please create a federated data source connection using the CREATE CONNECTION command for the same table provider, then create a catalog based on
the connection with a CREATE FOREIGN CATALOG command to reference the tables therein.
SQLSTATE: 0AKUC

Any suggestion I wonder if this a GCP config to something I am missing in the Databricks config
